# Calculate average by grouping using pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, average

I would like to get average of amount by date i.e.,
for eg:- my dataframe is like

**It should take unique count of months as denominator and sum of all data in the amounts as numerator**

```
Date        amount
2021-12-13  234.89
2021-12-06  456.9
2021-11-26  453.56
2021-11-19  453
2021-11-12  222.4
2021-10-29  123.4
2021-10-22  433.99
2021-10-15  784.99
2021-10-06  678.99
```

average should be sum of all amount values/count of months using pandas dataframe grouping.
in the above example average=sum of amount/3.

Comment: you want to groupby dates or month?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your question @Swetha ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit, IIUC:

```
df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.month
num_of_months = df["Month"].nunique()

df['avg_per_month'] = sum(df['amount'])/num_of_months
```

Comment: I don't want average for each month separately.while calculating average denominator should be count of how many months.In the above case there are 3 months.Numerator is the sum of all amounts column.

Comment: Alright, edited the answer.

Comment: How to add only negative values in the amount column if present

Comment: Change third line of code as : 
```df['avg_per_month'] = sum(df[df['amount'] < 0]['amount'])/num_of_months```.

Also, Please upvote and accept answers if you find them useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to calculate the average "amount" per month:

```
>> df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
>> df["amount"].sum() / df["Date"].dt.strftime("%m/%y").nunique()
1280.7066666666667
```

Here we're calculating the number of unique year/months, meaning that your max count won't be 12, in case your months cover more than a year. Then, we use that as denominator of the total "amount".

---

**Old answer (did not solve the correct problem):**

First of all, let's treat your "Date" column as a datetime:

```
>> df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
```

You can use [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to group by month of each date (`freq="M"`), select the `"amount"` column and calculate the mean of each group using `.mean()`

```
>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="M"))["amount"].mean()
Date
2021-12-13    234.89
2021-12-06    456.90
2021-11-26    453.56
2021-11-19    453.00
2021-11-12    222.40
2021-10-29    123.40
2021-10-22    433.99
2021-10-15    784.99
2021-10-06    678.99
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```